# How to create separate fields from Period code column(combined year, date and month) in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with column named PERIODCODE as

```
PERIODCODE 

20211401 
20211402 
20211403
```

I have used below code to separate out Year, Date and Month information and create new fields -

```
import datetime
df["date"] = pd.datetime(df["PERIODCODE"])
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```

Results I am getting with this are incorrect.
Below Output I am seeking

```
PERIODCODE| Year | Month |Key|

20211401 |2021|Jan|Jan-21|
20211402 |2021|Feb|Feb-21|
20211403 |2021|Mar|Mar-21|
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `format` parameter to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) here `YYYYDDMM` and for custom strings use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["PERIODCODE"], format='%Y%d%m')
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%b')
df['key'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%b-%y')
print (df)
   PERIODCODE       date  year month     key
0    20211401 2021-01-14  2021   Jan  Jan-21
1    20211402 2021-02-14  2021   Feb  Feb-21
2    20211403 2021-03-14  2021   Mar  Mar-21
```

Comment: It gives year as 1970 instead of 2021, Jan for all 3 rows of month and key as Jan-70